# How do I route my login controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using a homegrown (developers no longer around) web framework that has built in Spring security.

There is a LoginController that every request is redirected to until the user logs in.

The LoginController is mapped to use the context URL, e.g. my-company/login.do

```
public class LoginController {
public LoginController() {
}

@RequestMapping(
    value = {"/login.do"},
    method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
public String showLogin() {
    return "login";
}
```

For my application, I need to change that mapping to my-company/**admin**/login.do

The LoginController is coming in from a Maven dependency, so I CANNOT MODIFY that class

Is there any way to modify the existing LoginController to route to the extended url?

Comment: I'm not sure how we could possibly answer this without knowing the framework.

Comment: @Falmarri I don't know much about Spring security, but I don't think the solution depends on the framework, it's just doing the normal Spring security injection. I guess what I need to know is, I can Autowire the LoginController in my Configuration class. But is there any way to modify the mapping there?

Comment: Spring profiles may be an option here Create a new login controller with the necessary mapping and annotated with @Profile(name="xyz"). Start the server with vm arg -Dspring.profiles.active=xyz. New controller should override the old.

Comment: @AlanHay wouldn't that pull in both?

Comment: If you extend the first class then then I would expect only the 2nd to be loaded. Maybe......! Worth a quick spin.

Comment: In late news, I could not figure out the solution, but I was able to configure our software to accept the original url. Meanwhile I think it is a good question, so I will leave it open

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you want it to be located at "my-company/admin/login.do" when it is located at "my-company/login.do", I would start by changing

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = {"/login.do"},
    method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
public String showLogin() {
    return "login";
}
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = {"/admin/login.do"},
    method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
public String showLogin() {
    return "login";
}
```

However, if you still need the old location too, you might be better of copying the class and making a specific one for your admin login.

Also, this is just where I would start.  Odds are that the rest of your application expects this code to be located where it is, so you could easily break the integration with the rest of your code by doing this.

Comment: I don't need the old location, but as I said, I cannot modify the original class, it is coming in as a Maven dependency. I won't break the rest of the code. This is a dependency but I only need to modify the mapping for my application, and there it would be consistent

Comment: @VictorGrazi If you cannot modify the original class, exactly how do you intend to modify it?  Just because it comes in as a maven dependency doesn't mean you can't modify it.  If your solution was modular, but the code above is yours, it just means you're working on the wrong module.  Find the right module, check it out, compile, increase the version number, do a "mvn install" and then make the module that downloads it use the new version number.  If it is not your code, you're probably approaching it from the wrong angle.

Comment: Edwin - This is a corporate standard framework I need to use. I really cannot modify the original code because that would affect other users of the framework. What I need to do is somehow grab the LoginController before it is used and modify the mapping

Comment: @VictorGrazi then a standard servlet mapping entry would work pretty well, unless the servlet then attempts to hand off internally to other expected locations.  See Abdelhak's xml snippet for relocating the servelt's URL mapping; however, if it breaks, it's likely due to the servlets redirecting internally to the login (for example, on requesting a page requiring authentication without having the authentication prior).  And, if it's truly a standard, then the standard is likely to have a standard way of doing authentication, which this (and the workaround) is likely not following.